# How to pass multiple enum values to a variable in ReactJs typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I have `COLOR` enum declared as below..

```
export declare enum COLOR {
    RED = "RED",
    BLUE = "BLUE",
    YELLOW = "YELLOW"
}


interface IProps {
  config?: {
    disallowedColors: COLOR;
  };
```

now i need to access the value `config.disallowedColors`. If i want to pass multiple colors to `config.disallowedColors`, how do i do that ?? 
for e.g. i want `config.disallowedColors = red, yellow`

Can someone please shed some light here.

Comment: `COLOR[]` or `Array<COLOR>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the enum values are string, a simple array would suffice i.e. `config.disallowedColors = [COLOR.RED, COLOR.YELLOW]`.

When checking, you can leverage `includes` / `some` etc. to check if a flag is set e.g.

```
config.disallowedColors.includes(COLOR.RED);
```

It gets slightly more complicated when you need to check for multiple values, one option would be to create a temp array for the values you want to check are present, and then leverage `every` comparing each one to the target array i.e.

```
const flags = [COLOR.RED, COLOR.YELLOW];
const { disallowedColors } = config;
flags.every(c => disallowedColors.includes(c));
```

Alternatively, if you used a numerical value then you could leverage [Bitwise Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_logical_operators) to create a bit mask which would give you the same result (just in a different way) i.e.

```
// values should be ^2
enum COLOR {
  NONE = 0
  RED = 1,
  BLUE = 2,
  YELLOW = 4,
  ...
}
...
// setting multiple flags
const colors = COLOR.RED | COLOR.YELLOW;
// check for existence of single flag
const isRed = (colors & COLOR.RED) === COLOR.RED;
// check for existence of multiple flags
const flags = COLOR.RED | COLOR.YELLOW;
const hasMultiple = (colors & flags) === flags;
```